# How to deploy one K8s master on several servers, e.g. on 2 servers?

Tags: kubernetes

Sorry, as a noob I have no clue about how to deploy one K8s master node on several physical servers, e.g. deploy one master node on 2 servers? Not HA solution, just one master node.

Could anyone give me some hints or some links that I can read about this solution?

Thank a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, or the question needs more context. A "node" in Kubernetes contexts is always a specific server. So you are essentially asking "how can I deploy one server on two servers".

What you *can* do is have both of your physical servers act as hypervisors and then run your control plane ("master") node as a *virtual machine* on those. This is however out of scope for Kubernetes itself (unless you want to run delve into [KubeVirt](https://kubevirt.io) to run VMs via Kubernetes) and you are looking for a generic solution to host VMs. Hypervisors are a complicated domain, I would not recommend to run this yourself if you don't have the experience (unless you are willing to build it, but you want to run a Kubernetes cluster, not a hypervisor cluster).

If you add some context to your question (*why* do you want to do this? What are you trying to achieve by running a master node on two physical servers?), the answer might change.

Comment: Hi embik, Many thanks for your answer, I just thought about whether my idea could be possible. I have a little bit experience of openstack. By openstack, I can put 3 physical servers as control one node, just want to compare with K8s, cause i am noob.

Comment: I think you are mapping concepts a bit wrong. If you want to compare Kubernetes and OpenStack: A Kubernetes "Node" maps to a "Compute Node" in OpenStack, i.e. a node is _providing_ capacity to host workloads (containers for Kubernetes, virtual machines for OpenStack).